# WebStorm custom source roots

Tags: node.js, webstorm, require, node-modules

I am using WebStorm 2017.3 for Node.JS development, and I have a question about source roots.

I use [`app-module-path`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) to reduce the number of relative paths between my files in `require` statements, to get rid of stuff like `require('../../../utils/common/stuff')`. What I do is, on the first line of my app I call

```
require('app-module-path').addPath(__dirname);
```

Which makes it possible to do things like `require('src/utils/common/stuff')`, if the `src` folder is located directly under the path added to `app-module-path`.

However, when using these custom source roots, while the code itself works, WebStorm seems unable to resolve the required files. Let's say I have this structure:

```
app.js
node_modules
  |- some_module
       |- xyz.js     
src
  |- routes
       |- foo.js
       |- bar.js
  |- utils
       |- stuff.js
```

WebStorm can of course successfully resolve the following "normal" require statements from `foo.js`:

```
require('./bar')
require('../utils/stuff')
require('some_module/xyz')
```

The first two are of course relative, the last one is because `node_modules` is a source root (or whatever term is used).

If I now add the root path to `app-module-path`, all my files can successfully do:

```
require('src/utils/stuff')
```

...which I think looks much nicer than endless relative `../../../../` everywhere. However, while the code itself works fine since `src/utils/stuff` is found relative to the root folder, the file is not resolved by the IDE, meaning my required object/function becomes grey instead of purple/yellow, I cannot Ctrl+Click on any symbols within it or use any other IDE nice stuff, which is very annoying.

I've tried marking directories as *"Resource roots"*, but that doesn't make any difference; files required with absolute paths still cannot be resolved relative to resource roots. Basically what I'm after is the ability to configure additional folders to behave just like `node_modules`, and in the `Directories` setting, `node_modules` is marked as "Excluded", so it surely must be a completely separate setting controlling which folders are used as "require root folders" or "require search paths".

I've also tried making a symlink from `<root>/node_modules/src` to `<root>/src`, and while that makes it possible to Ctrl+Click on the actual file path `'src/utils/stuff'` in the require statement, it still doesn't resolve the object that was required, and it also causes WebStorm to issue a warning about the module not being listed in package.json (which, of course, is correct).

Is there any way to configure WebStorm with additional "require root folders"? Or is there a better way than `app-module-path` to get rid of "relative path hell" in require statements while still preserving WebStorm resolving/indexing capabilities?

Comment: Actually just noticed that if I mark my `src` folder as resource root then I can do `require('utils/stuff')` and get resolved types etc. I still get "module not installed" warnings though. Marking the *root* folder as a resource root and using require('src/utils/stuff') does however NOT work, as described in the question but I may be able to work out a working setup with this (I will probably move my src folder into an app folder and mark app as a resource root).